# KeyError: 0 when used in existing function, otherwise the code works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to do the following:

- I have data in long format organized by dates
- Sometimes, data is missing as it there is no record of it
- I found a solution by interpolating missing data using reindex which works fine when used outside of function, but for some reason, doesn't work when used inside of a function

```
def sum_customer_portfolio(country, sold_to):
    df = pd.merge(etl_customer_portfolio(), etl_week(), how="left", on=["Country", "GCAS"])
    df = df.loc[df["Country"].isin(country)]
    df = df.loc[df["Sold_to"].isin(sold_to)]

    df_week = etl_week()
    df_week = df_week.dropna(subset=["Sold_to"])
    df_week = df_week[["Week_num", "Date_range"]]
    df_week = df_week.drop_duplicates(subset=["Date_range"])

    sum_df = pd.merge(df, df_week, how="outer", on=["Week_num", "Date_range"])
    sum_df["Stat_unit_qty"] = sum_df["Stat_unit_qty"].fillna(0, axis=0)
    sum_df[["Country", "Sold_to", "Customer"]] = sum_df[["Country", "Sold_to", "Customer"]].fillna(method="ffill",
                                                                                                   axis=0)
    sum_df = sum_df.fillna("DUMMY_NOT_USE").replace("DUMMY_NOT_USE", np.nan)

    reindex_subset = sum_df[["GCAS", "Week_num", "Stat_unit_qty"]]
    reindex_subset = reindex_subset.dropna()
    reindex_subset = reindex_subset.set_index("Week_num")

    reindex_subset = (reindex_subset.groupby("GCAS").apply(
        lambda x: x.reindex(list(range(reindex_subset.index.min(), reindex_subset.index.max() + 1)), fill_value=0))
        .drop("GCAS", axis=1).
        reset_index("GCAS").
        fillna(0).
        reset_index())
    reindex_subset = reindex_subset.drop(columns=["Stat_unit_qty"])

    final_df = pd.merge(sum_df, reindex_subset, how="outer", on=["GCAS", "Week_num"])

    current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M%S")

    # return sum_df.to_excel(f"CUSTOMER_PORTFOLIO-{current_date}.xlsx", sheet_name="GCAS_SUM", index=False)
    return final_df
```

Code above keeps giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 103, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 135, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 51, in pandas._libs.index.Float64Engine._maybe_get_bool_indexer
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 161, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._unpack_bool_indexer
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 167, in <module>
    sum_customer_portfolio(country=["Croatia", "Slovenia"], sold_to=[2000829798, 2000558171]).to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="GCAS_SUM")
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 113, in sum_customer_portfolio
    reindex_subset = (reindex_subset.groupby(["GCAS", "Sold_to"]).apply(
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1253, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1287, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 783, in apply
    result_values, mutated = splitter.fast_apply(f, sdata, group_keys)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 1328, in fast_apply
    return libreduction.apply_frame_axis0(sdata, f, names, starts, ends)
  File "pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx", line 369, in pandas._libs.reduction.apply_frame_axis0
  File "pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx", line 428, in pandas._libs.reduction.BlockSlider.__init__
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3430, in __getitem__
    indexer = convert_to_index_sliceable(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2329, in convert_to_index_sliceable
    return idx._convert_slice_indexer(key, kind="getitem")
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\numeric.py", line 242, in _convert_slice_indexer
    return self.slice_indexer(key.start, key.stop, key.step, kind=kind)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5686, in slice_indexer
    start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5894, in slice_locs
    end_slice = self.get_slice_bound(end, "right")
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5808, in get_slice_bound
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5802, in get_slice_bound
    slc = self.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

When loading the data directly from Excel (same data that produced by the function), for example, "CUSTOMER_PORTFOLIO-11082021_234057.xlsx" and running the following code:

```
sum_df = pd.read_excel("CUSTOMER_PORTFOLIO-11082021_234057.xlsx")

reindex_subset = sum_df[["GCAS", "Week_num", "Stat_unit_qty"]]
reindex_subset = reindex_subset.dropna()
reindex_subset = reindex_subset.set_index("Week_num")
reindex_subset = (reindex_subset.groupby("GCAS").apply(
    lambda x: x.reindex(list(range(reindex_subset.index.min(), reindex_subset.index.max() + 1)), fill_value=0))
    .drop("GCAS", axis=1).
    reset_index("GCAS").
    fillna(0).
    reset_index())
reindex_subset = reindex_subset.drop(columns=["Stat_unit_qty"])

final_df = pd.merge(sum_df, reindex_subset, how="outer", on=["GCAS", "Week_num"])
```

The code gives me results that I want.

What am I missing? I tried searching for this on SO overflow, but no success as of yet. I have tried resetting index, but unfortunately, it didn't help.

**UPDATE:** Pasted the full error traceback. Moreover, as I said above, when I run the function without the part of the code that "reindexes" the data, the code works just fine. I have also tried and still no luck:

```
df_new = df.copy(deep=True)
df_week= df_week.copy(deep=True)
```

And when I run the "reindex" part of the code on a finished .xlsx, it works just fine, which is strange in itself.

Comment: `KeyError` means that you try to access a key that does not exist. If it works outside a function but not within it has probably something to do with variable scopes. Have a look if you're missing a `global` statement or something.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, give this [guide to the python traceback](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/) a read - it's really helpful, and the full traceback is critical to debugging (for us as well as you). Before asking a question on SO, try to break it down into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help debug if we're not able to reproduce the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Please show the full traceback. There's no `raise KeyError(key)` line in the code you posted.

Comment: Maybe look at what `etl_customer_portfolio()` and `etl_week()` are returning?

Comment: @MDR - both `etl_customer_portfolio()` and `etl_week()` are returning their own respective dataframes which is OK.
@MichaelDelgado and @Barmar - posted the full error traceback